# Passing SubQuery into OpenQuery with AS400 Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ibm-midrange, linked-server, openquery

I have a Linked Server to the AS400 here.  I'm trying to pull data from a field, but it is pulling over a  million records when I only need about 20k.

I have a list of IDs that I need, and I'm trying to figure out how to pass that list into the OpenQuery.

Here is my OpenQuery:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(AS400, '
    SELECT 
        IMITNO, IMITD1, IMITD2, IMMFNO, IMBMTP, IMDSCO 
      FROM AS400.APLUS2FLE.ITMST 
      WHERE IMDSCO != ''Y''
')
```

I want to add `WHERE IMITNO IN (SELECT item_id FROM as400_item_scope)` but the as400_item_scope table is on the SQL machine, not the AS400.  I looked at several examples and I can pass in a single variable, but I don't understand how to pass in a list/query like this.

I'm using latest SSMS, but SQL Server Version is 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can't as far as I know...

Two options..

1. Insert the results of `SELECT item_id FROM as400_item_scope` into a (temporary?) table on the IBM i and then reference that table in your openquery.
2. build a comma delimited string with from the results of `SELECT item_id FROM as400_item_scope` and include that in your openquery string.

Depending on how many records are returned, you might run into issues with statement size trying to use option #2.  Db2 for IBM i supports SQL statement of up to 2,097,152 bytes...